# Безопасность AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, безопасность

Можно мне разъяснить про безопасность AJAX запросов. Если у меня работает такой код:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ajax.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#Res').html(result);
        }
```

Может ли злоумышленник отправить POST-запрос напрямую и изменить таким образом настройку в системе? В каком случае он это может сделать? Как это предотвратить? Какие-то секретные данные я не могу очевидно передавать, ведь их можно перехватить? Знаю про проверку заголовка на ajax это или нет, но это не надёжный метод

Comment: в данном случае не важно ajax это запрос, или обычный. безопасность обработки логики лежит на ваших плечах на стороне серверного кода. Обычно, чтобы что-либо изменять/удалять, пользователь должен быть авторизован. Так что ваша задача, определить имеет он права на выполнение запрашиваемого действия или нет. и, повторюсь, не важно это ajax-запрос или обычный.

Comment: О-о, это вечный вопрос. Пожалуй, не столько отвечу, сколько сориентирую на поиски по слову "стеганография". При открытом (незащищенном) канале связи это почти единственный способ защищаться...

Comment: Стеганография - это костыль. Нормально шифровать данные можно и поверх открытого канала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы кто то изменил конфиги, и подобные "скрытые" вещи, то нужно делать как минимум авторизацию, и ставить "юзерам" группы. И если это такая группа, то изменять, если пользователи - то нет прав... По такому типу работает.

Answer (score 3):

[Ajax](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) (Asynchronous Javascript And Xml), это аббривеатура означающая технологию отправки запроса на веб-сервер без перезагрузки страницы. В корне этой технологии лежит JavaScript-объект `XMLHttpRequest`, который отправляет на сервер обычный [HTTP](https://habrahabr.ru/post/215117/) запрос, ничем не отличающийся от любого другого, выполненного по средствам любого инструмента (переходу по адресной строке браузера или утилиты CURL)

> Может ли злоумышленник отправить POST-запрос напрямую и изменить таким
> образом настройку в системе?

Когда вы проектируете API-бекенда (т.н. серверная часть, в вашем случае ajax.php), то необходимо понимать, что обратиться к этому API может любой (в случае публичной сети, такой как интернет). Для того, что бы защитить приватную информацию (настройки, в вашем случае), вы должны организовать [*авторизацию*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) пользователя.

Распространенным сценарием может считаться следующий:

- [Аутентификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5) пользователя на сервере (вашем или доверенном) путем отправки неких авторизационных данных, таких как логин и пароль.
- Получения ключа на этом сервере
- Отправка этого ключа вместе с запросом на сервер для выполнения некого полезного действия (в вашем примере к ajax.php)

Сервер должен проверять такой ключ на предмет принадлежности конкретному авторизованному пользователю и разрешать/запрещать обрабатывать запрос в зависимости от результата проверки.

Comment: [авторизацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) вы тоже организовать

Comment: Что-то каша у вас из аутентификации и авторизации. логин/пароль/получение ключа - всё это аутентификация, а вот дать ли тебе вот этот ресурс по вот этому ключу - авторизация.

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо. (_ты бы знал, как я с именами классов мучаюсь_)

Comment: что то я там слово "должны " пропустил

Comment: в вашем распространном сценарии первый пункт это как раз таки аутентификация. То есть ввод логина пароля и их проверка на стэковерфлоу это аунтеификация (проверка подлинности), а вот проверка можете ли вы с вашей репутацией писать комментарии, постить ответы, править вопросы/ответы и так далее это уже авторизация, т.е. проверка разрешений для пользователя.

Comment: Я имел ввиду что на странице page где располагается кнопка юзер авторизован. На ajax.php прилетает запрос. А эта страница откуда знает авторизован этот юзер или нет? ))

Comment: В общем случае, сервер не должен отдавать неавторизованному пользователю страницу, которая работает с данными, требующими авторизации.

Comment: А что делать если ajax штука с самого начала задумывалась для вещей не требующих авторзации? Например: комментарии к статье...